# Performing filter based Queries on Salesforce using SOQL

Tags: soql, filters

I want to write an SOQL Query to ensure that contacts with the name John Johnson , together with all contacts with Last name Smith (excluding Benjamin Smith) will be selected. Please advise how to write this SOQL, I am using the dummy data and querying from Contact Object in Salesforce. I do not seem to be getting it correctly. Kind of new to this.

Comment: What you have so far? Show your code psl.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question to show what research you have done and to state just where you are stuck. Without this your question will likely be closed without answer.

Comment: BTW, SOQL struggles with accurate matching against Contact's Name Field especially when your data includes spaces in names or MiddleName is enabled on your org. You will do better with SOSL in this case.

Comment: Please do not post the same question under multiple SFSE accounts. If you're new to writing queries, please start with Trailhead.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below query, it should give you all the contacts with lastname 'Smith' and a record with name 'John Johnson'. Edit the returned fields according to your requirement.

SELECT AccountId,Email,FirstName,LastName FROM Contact WHERE (FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Johnson') OR LastName = 'Smith'